# Testing for 'lazy loaded' null IEnumerable in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I've simplified a piece of a deferred execution code, but how on earth do you check the following is not null/empty without wrapping it in a try/catch?

```
    string[] nullCollection = null;
    IEnumerable<string> ienumerable = new[] { nullCollection }.SelectMany(a => a);

    bool isnull = ienumerable == null; //returns false
    bool isany = ienumerable.Any(); //throws an exception
```

Comment: @MrinalKamboj It's a NullReferenceException thrown because the SelectManyIterator is called with a null element.

Comment: @RB. then its tricky, none of the above points of mine will hold

Answer (score 3):

You just need to make your lambda more resilient to null entries:

```
IEnumerable<string> ienumerable = new[] { nullCollection }
    .SelectMany(a => a ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>());

bool isany = ienumerable.Any(); // Sets isany to 'false'
```

Comment: This is nice, but If I'm just passed an `IEnumerable<string>` argument I guess I'm stuck...

Comment: @maxp Yep - there is a fundamental problem with the construction of `ienumerable`. I don't think there's any fixing it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that, because that's the same as asking "how can I tell that method will not throw `NullReferenceException` without invoking it?". Having no other clues the only way is actually invoke such methods and observe the result. Enumerating `IEnumerable` is just invoking bunch of `MoveNext` calls on it's enumerator, and any such call might throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the current item from the enumerator is null

```
string[] nullCollection = null;
IEnumerable<string> ienumerable = new[] { nullCollection }.SelectMany(a => a);

bool isnull = ienumerable.GetEnumerator().Current == null;
if (!isnull)
{
    bool isany = ienumerable.Any();
}
```

Comment: This won't work - when you call `MoveNext()` to iterate through it will crash if it comes across a `null` element. Ultimately, the projection function is going to get evaluated for each element, and it will cause a crash when it is called with a null value - I don't think there is any getting around that.

Comment: @RB. W/o `MoveNext()`, there's no `Current` :). Is it back to square One

Comment: This is quite incorrect answer - accessing `Current` before `MoveNext` has undefined behavior - most likely here it always returns `null`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I said that :)

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Yes - I think we've all said the same thing in slightly different ways :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Linq methods are extension methods on IEnumerable, you could wrap these extensions further: with an extension method, the object receiving the extension can be null.

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SafeSelectMany<T, TCollection, TResult>(
            this IEnumerable<T> source, 
            Func<T, IEnumerable<TCollection>> collectionSelector, 
            Func<T, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        IEnumerable<TResult> result = source.SelectMany(collectionSelector, resultSelector);
        return result;
    }
```

You could also return an empty `List<TResult>` instead of `null` for `source==null`.